# Error c++ 20 #include <bits/stdc++.h>

Tags: c++20

Hola recientemente me cambié a la versión 20 de c++ y tengo el siguiente error al inicializar **<bits/stdc++.h>** y al parecer no es problema de instalación, no tengo ningún problema con las otras librerías adjunto captura del problema.

**Error:**
mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:237:47: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
|| (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado a hacer un clean después de cambiar la versión? El código ensamblado puede no ser compatible entre versiones

Answer (score 0):

**Solución:** al parecer el error venía de la versión de MinGW  que está en [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)
lo solucioné descargando directamente desde [aquí](https://winlibs.com/) en Release versions.